# Why in my Arduino test (about the blinking LED) coding the pin as an output or not does not change the final effect?

Tags: arduino

Here i commented the  pinmode section:

```
  void setup() {

  //pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

in my test is equal to:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

it only seems that the LED blinks weakly.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for digitalWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/):

> Write a HIGH or a LOW value to a digital pin.
>
> If the pin has been configured as an OUTPUT with pinMode(), its
>   voltage will be set to the corresponding value: 5V (or 3.3V on 3.3V
>   boards) for HIGH, 0V (ground) for LOW.
>
> If the pin is configured as an INPUT, digitalWrite() will enable
>   (HIGH) or disable (LOW) the internal pullup on the input pin. It is
>   recommended to set the pinMode() to INPUT_PULLUP to enable the
>   internal pull-up resistor. See the digital pins tutorial for more
>   information.
>
> If you do not set the pinMode() to OUTPUT, and connect an LED to a
>   pin, when calling digitalWrite(HIGH), the LED may appear dim. Without
>   explicitly setting pinMode(), digitalWrite() will have enabled the
>   internal pull-up resistor, which acts like a large current-limiting
>   resistor.